# add_image_size not working with after_switch_theme

Tags: hooks, images

This is a weird one - this exact code works with `after_setup_theme` but not with `after_switch_theme`. Of course I would rather use `after_switch_theme` because `after_setup_theme` runs all the time - but it just will not work.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpdocs_theme_setup' );

function wpdocs_theme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

    add_image_size( 'hero_image', 1920, 800, true);
    add_image_size( 'hero_image_md_lg', 991, 490, true);
    add_image_size( 'hero_image_md', 767, 460, true);
    add_image_size( 'hero_image_sm', 549, 575, true);
    ...
}
```

For reference: yes, I am switching the theme. Yes, I am regenerating the thumbnails. And in my `wpdocs_theme_setup` function I'm also adding custom roles that work regardless of which hook is being used. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason adding custom roles works on `after_switch_theme` is because roles are saved in the database. In fact, because it saves to the database, it should *not* run on `after_setup_theme`.

`add_image_size()`, on the other hand, does not save anything to the database, so needs to run on every page load, and needs to be hooked on a hook that runs for every page load. So `after_setup_theme` is the correct hook to use.

Comment: Ohhhh I thought it was setting up custom image sizes that would be stored as a setting somewhere in the database. Got it, thanks.